# Is it possible to obtain n-butane by treating halopropane grignard reagent with methanol?

Tags: erratum, grignard-reagent

> [image]

The answer is a,b.

[image]

My mechanism however doesn't give n-butane when R is propyl. Is this a case of textbook errata?

---

Himanshu Pandey, *Advanced Problems In Organic Chemistry*, *9th edition* 2017

Comment: This is clearly an error. b & c will give n-butane

Comment: @Waylander Won't sec-butyl give isobutane?

Comment: No. s-bu grignard has the Mg on the second carbon of a n-butyl chain (it is made from 2-halo-butane) so replacing that with H gives n-butane.

Comment: @AvnishKabaj Not surprisingly, isobutyl (not listed here) (and also tert-butyl) would give isobutane.

Comment: @Zhe How? Some fancy mechanism?

Comment: It's just quenching the Grignard. Take the anion equivalent and add a proton. @AvnishKabaj